# dynamically generate react components from data from an object as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

**Context:** trying to build a simple todo list app in react and typescript for educational purposes.

**What I'm trying to do:** Render as many ProjectMenuItem components as there are individual projects in my `projects` object, using the title of the project as props to pass into the components. "Project 1, Project 2, Project 3" should render to the screen as p elements.

**What happens instead:** The app does not compile and I get an error saying: `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {projectName}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

**ProjectMenuItem component:**

```
export function ProjectMenuItem(projectName: any){

    return(
        <p>{projectName}</p>
    );

}
```

**Parent Component:**

```
export function ProjectList(){
    
    const projects = {
        project1: {
            title: 'Project 1',
        },
        project2: {
            title: 'Project 2',
        },
        project3: {
            title: 'Project 3',
        },
    };
    
    function generateProjectMenuItems() {
        const projectMenuItems = [];
        for (const project in projects) {
            const projectName: string = projects[project as keyof typeof projects].title;
            projectMenuItems.push(<ProjectMenuItem projectName={projectName} />);
        }
        
        return projectMenuItems;
    }

    return(
        <div className="project-list flexbox">
            <p>project components go here</p>
            {generateProjectMenuItems()}
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Have tried:** I know it is saying I should use it as an array, so I tried mapping the projectMenuItems array to an array of span elements containing the components, but this results in the same error message.

`return projectMenuItems.map(el => <span className="project-span" key={Math.random().toString()}>{el}</span>);`

*TL;DR I am trying to generate components for each object in a larger object and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Very new to react.*

Comment: If you want multiple `<ProjectMenuItem>` rendered, you need to iterate over the array rather than just passing it as `{generateProjectMenuItems()}` - you could simply do `{genateProjectMenuItems().map(item=>item)}` but your code is not really put together the way React expects in the first place.

Comment: The only thing that immediately jumps out is that you're not destructuring the project name from the component props object: `export function ProjectMenuItem({ projectName })...`

Comment: @Andy - OP is trying to render an array of components as the raw array,.

Comment: @RandyCasburn `generateProjectMenuItems` returns an array of components so it should work ok.

Comment: @RandyCasburn What would be the way that react should expect the code?

Comment: @manski - it is unusual to perform data transformation inside of a component. It is preferred/expected(?) the component will be provided the data in a form it can use. So transformation would happen elsewhere. All that is conjecture and doesn't make a difference anyway for two reasons. 1) you have mocked data in your question, so we don't really know what the data looks like 2) React is quite flexible

Answer (score 3):

Your `ProjectMenuItem` component isn't quite right. You want to accept the props as a (destructured) object:

```
export function ProjectMenuItem({ projectName }: { projectName: string }) {
```

As it is, React is providing it with the entire props object, which it receives as `projectName`. When it tries to render this in `<p>{projectName}</p>` it is giving you the error "Objects are not valid".

Comment: Thanks. This helped with part of the problem but I still get the same error. I'm able to map to regular html elements but when I try to include my imported component in my map function, it still compile errors.

Comment: @manski I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-vtqpb2?file=/src/App.tsx) with your code and the amendment. It works fine, although it does warn about the missing `key` prop on the projects. Perhaps these other compile errors are due to other components that have similar problems.

Comment: Thanks that is very kind of you!

Answer (score 0):

So this is probably not best practices, but this is how I ended up solving the problem yesterday. I am very open to feedback on things I could do better. I wrote it this way because it was the only way I could have my code work when it loaded from an empty (null) state when the app renders at first, because trying to run `Object.keys()` or `map()` on things that were `null` was making my app crash, so I wrapped my logic in a hook and conditional rendering to make things work.

**Parent Component:**

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import { AllContext } from "../App";
import ProjectMenuItem from "./ProjectMenuItem";


export default function ProjectList(){
//use context to pass state from root component
    const {allProjects, selectedProject, currentTask} = React.useContext(AllContext);
    const [allProjectsCopy, setAllProjects] = allProjects;
    //make state for conditional rendering

    const[displayProjects, setDisplayProjects] = React.useState<any>(null);
    let projects: any;



    //run this only when state updates
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Hello from the Project List component!', allProjectsCopy);
        if(allProjectsCopy !== null){
            console.log('allProjectsCopy updated and is NOT null.');
            projects = Object.keys(allProjectsCopy);
            let displayProjectsUpdate = projects.map((item: any)=>(
                <div key={item}>
                    <ProjectMenuItem projectName={item} />
                </div>
                )
            );
            setDisplayProjects(displayProjectsUpdate);
        }
      }, [allProjectsCopy]);


    return(
        <div className="project-list flexbox">
            <p>project components go here</p>
            {(displayProjects !== null) ? displayProjects : null}
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Child Components:**

```
export default function ProjectMenuItem(props: any) {

    return(
        <div className="project-menu-item flexbox">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-two-tone/48/null/overview-pages-3.png" alt="icon" role="button" tabIndex={0} aria-label="Clickable image" />
          <h3 className="project-item-heading">{props.projectName}</h3>
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/null/edit-property.png" alt="icon" role="button" tabIndex={0} aria-label="Clickable image"/> 
        </div>
    );


}
```